# How to create a custom get method snippet in VsCode

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, code-snippets

I wanted to create a custom get method snippet on VsCode and I know about the users snippets so created one, but it did not came out as expected.

I tried creating a snippet like this one (for java):

```
"get": {
        "prefix": "get",
        "body": [
            "public ${1:Type} get${2:Property} () {",
            "\treturn ${2: property};",
            "}"
        ],
        "description": "Creates a get method"
    }
```

But when I type the first "parameter" of the snippet, it is correlated with the third (on the return line), what I wanted but in all in lower case, and if possible camel case, so the result would be something like this:

```
public Type getPropertyName(){
    return propertyName;
}
```

and not this:

```
public Type getPropertyName(){
    return PropertyName;
}
```

Comment: I don't mean to be rude, but why don't you use a Java IDE? Eclipse can generate _getters_ and _setters_ via a context menu. You just type the property name and its class. Then put the mouse pointer over the name, right click to bring up the context menu and choose the _generate_ option.

Comment: I know that this is a thing in eclipse, but I like using Vscode because it is light and and versitile. I don't want to download an IDE just for a language, you know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some research about Regex I could bring a solution to it! The sinppet to the get method would be this one:

```
"get": {
        "prefix": "get",
        "body": [
            "public ${1:Type} get${2:Property} () {",
            "\treturn ${2/([A-Z])/${1:/downcase}/};",
            "}"
        ],
        "description": "Creates a get method"
    }
```